# Can't get my C# / ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app to work via a docker container over ssl

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, ssl, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying and failing at deploying an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app in a docker container over ssl. I have a mystery crash issue of which I can't seem to find the cause. I can't even get a meaningful error. It works perfectly when I run it locally and it even works over docker "non-ssl" lol. But for some reason when I follow the Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-6.0, it fails.

This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Development -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "amaranth.dll"]
```

This is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  data:

services:
  postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg:
    image: postgres
    # explicit container name
    container_name: postgresql_vlt_bg
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql_vlt_bg
  amaranth_main:
    container_name: amaranth_main
    links:
      - postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg
    depends_on:
      - postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:80
      - 8001:443
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=<MY PASSWORD HERE>
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

This is my `Program.cs` file. It might seem random that I'm including this but according to my logs it's where the error is being thrown.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using amaranth.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace amaranth
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                db.Database.Migrate();
            }
            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                    {
                        // Set properties and call methods on options
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

This is the logs where it fails:

```
<MYUSERNAME>@<MYCOMPUTERNAME> amaranth % docker-compose up
Creating network "amaranth_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "amaranth_data" with default driver
Building amaranth_main
[+] Building 32.7s (14/14) FINISHED                                                                                                                                 
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0                                                                                           0.1s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0                                                                                              0.1s
 => [build-env 1/5] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0@sha256:<RANDOM SHA256 SUM HERE>                              0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 38.79kB                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0@sha256:<RANDOM SHA256 SUM HERE>                             0.0s
 => CACHED [build-env 2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [build-env 3/5] COPY . ./                                                                                                                                  0.4s
 => [build-env 4/5] RUN dotnet restore                                                                                                                        26.3s
 => [build-env 5/5] RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out                                                                                                       5.7s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 => CACHED [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=build-env /app/out .                                                                                                      0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:<RANDOM SHA256 SUM HERE>                                                                   0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/amaranth_amaranth_main                                                                                                      0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
WARNING: Image for service amaranth_main was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating postgresql_vlt_bg ... done
Creating amaranth_main     ... done
Attaching to postgresql_vlt_bg, amaranth_main
postgresql_vlt_bg           | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgresql_vlt_bg           | This user must also own the server process.
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgresql_vlt_bg           | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgresql_vlt_bg           | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgresql_vlt_bg           | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgresql_vlt_bg           | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgresql_vlt_bg           | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgresql_vlt_bg           | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgresql_vlt_bg           | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgresql_vlt_bg           | creating configuration files ... ok
postgresql_vlt_bg           | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgresql_vlt_bg           | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgresql_vlt_bg           | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgresql_vlt_bg           | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgresql_vlt_bg           | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           | waiting for server to start....2022-09-26 03:15:59.900 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:15:59.902 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:15:59.908 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-09-26 03:15:59 UTC
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:15:59.913 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgresql_vlt_bg           |  done
postgresql_vlt_bg           | server started
postgresql_vlt_bg           | CREATE DATABASE
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           | waiting for server to shut down...2022-09-26 03:16:00.145 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgresql_vlt_bg           | .2022-09-26 03:16:00.147 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:16:00.149 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:16:00.150 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:16:00.169 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgresql_vlt_bg           |  done
postgresql_vlt_bg           | server stopped
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:16:00.263 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:16:00.263 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:16:00.263 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:16:00.267 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:16:00.272 UTC [62] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-09-26 03:16:00 UTC
postgresql_vlt_bg           | 2022-09-26 03:16:00.276 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
amaranth_main               | info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
amaranth_main               |       Entity Framework Core 6.0.5 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL:6.0.4+<RANDOM CHECKSUM HERE>' with options: None
amaranth_main               | Unhandled exception. Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to [::1]:5432
amaranth_main               |  ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address [::1]:5432
amaranth_main               |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
amaranth_main               |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
amaranth_main               |    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
amaranth_main               |    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
amaranth_main               |    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
amaranth_main               |    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|191_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
amaranth_main               |    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
amaranth_main               |    at Npgsql.UnpooledConnectorSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
amaranth_main               |    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
amaranth_main               |    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
amaranth_main               |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
amaranth_main               |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
amaranth_main               |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
amaranth_main               |    at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
amaranth_main               |    at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
amaranth_main               |    at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
amaranth_main               |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
amaranth_main               |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
amaranth_main               |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
amaranth_main               |    at amaranth.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/Program.cs:line 25
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping amaranth_main     ... done
Stopping postgresql_vlt_bg ... done
<MYUSERNAME>@<MYCOMPUTERNAME> amaranth %
```

Line 25 in Program.cs is `db.Database.Migrate();`.

So why isn't it working?

Comment: I've seen a number of cases this year when Migrate fails after an update. The cause has been an issue with the connection to the database failing.  It could be the connection string, or Authentication, or TLS.  The error says : [database system will be owned by user "postgres"].  So for migration to work you need to use a login for with owner postgres.  Check your connection string to see what database is being used and permisions.

Comment: This is my db string: `"db": "Server=postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg;Database=amaranth_vaultvid_tests;User Id=amaranth_vaultvid_test_user;Password=<MY PASSWORD HERE>;Integrated Security=true"`  

I changed it to `"db": "Server=postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg;Database=amaranth_vaultvid_tests;User Id=postgres;Password=;Integrated Security=true"`  

And it still gave the same error

Comment: have you tried by removing `Integrated Security=true` part from connection string.

Comment: I tried removing `Integrated Security=true`, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to `appsetting.json`:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url":  "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
    },
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:5001"
    }
  },
  "EndpointDefaults": {
    "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:5001",
    "Protocols": "Http1"
  }
},
```

And I added the following to the `amaranth_main:` section of `docker-compose.yml`

```
ports:
  - 8000:5000
  - 8001:5001
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Release
  - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=${Kestrel_Cert_Password}
  - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=${Kestrel_Cert_Rel_Path}
volumes:
      - ${Kestrel_Cert_Abs_Path}:/https:ro
```

And I replaced the `env-file` section of the `postgresql_MENTIONvlt_bg:` section of the `docker-compose.yml` with:

```
environment:
  - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
  - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
```

And I launched the app with `docker-compose --env-file .env up`, making sure that `POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD, POSTGRES_DB, Kestrel_Cert_Password, Kestrel_Cert_Rel_Path,` and `Kestrel_Cert_Abs_Path` are referenced in the `.env` file.

After this it worked when I visited `https://localhost:8001` in my browser.